# How do I make bunch of collection instances follow along a curve?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints, path

[image]

[image]

I have these certain collection instances, and I want them to make a perfect arc in my frame,
although I tried to manually position them in the scene, it is not giving me the desired results, how do I create a curve and then make these instances follow it perfectly...

[image]

Comment: The red line is what I don't want the curve to be like, while the blue line is how I'd like it to be.....

Comment: To me this looks like you have to tweak the curve which the objects follow until it fits the desired outcome. Or do you have any values to calculate to get the result? What is a "perfect arc"?

Comment: I just want to have a curve that looks perfect and has good curvature

Comment: do they need to be collection instances?

Comment: Not necessarily, they can also be seperate objects but having them as instances makes m y file lightweight and not laggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a curve, and a collection of instances at the origin, Z up, X across, this little GN group will spread the collection along the curve:

[image]

.. with adjustments for spread start, end, back/front offset, and swivel, all of which can be keyed, if you need that, too:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow Robin, this is amazing to see, can you distill what's happening inside Geo nodes?

Comment: All it's doing is sampling the curve ( and its directions) with _Curve to Points_, and instancing the members of your collection onto the points.  The rest is tweaks of rotation, translation, which you can expand on, if you like. The Max and Min prevent the curve from being trimmed to 0 length, because then you lose all the direction information.

Comment: can you help me out here mate, thanks a lot: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298733/why-is-this-geometry-node-setup-not-rotating-around-a-central-pivot-point-but-ar