# Why is this Geometry Node setup not rotating around a central pivot point but around its own axis?

Tags: animation, mesh, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

[image]

Currently working on this Geo nodes setup where the cards are supposed to fanout in this fashion:

[image]

Question where this answer was posted:
[How do I make bunch of collection instances follow along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298392/how-do-i-make-bunch-of-collection-instances-follow-along-a-curve/298447?noredirect=1#comment515073_298447)

Link to blend file:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Atharava.. your file is quite confusing for a stranger to your project.. not sure what I can abandon. The GN effect here actually _creates_ instances .. would it be OK to abandon your controller-parents, and animate the created instances themselves?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate instances around something there needs to be a thing to rotate them around.

[image: Some cards spread on a curve rotated around an empty]

I've added a *Card Rotation Origin* empty that they can rotate around. It is also important that the instanced [objects has an origin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/scene_layout/object/origin.html) in the place they should rotate around. Each of the objects in the *Card Objects* collection has their instance at the bottom of the object, where the curve should intersect with it. You can still animate the Geometry Nodes Modifier as you do in your file.

[image: Geometry nodes instancing a collection on a curve and rotates them to align with the position of an origin point object]

[image]